# How to debug JSPs in Netbeans and Glassfish

Tags: jsp, debugging, netbeans, glassfish

I have an enterprise application in netbeans with maven (4 projects) and I have java code in one of my JSP's (I know this is a bad practice) but I can't debug it, I mean, the debugger stops on java classes or servlets but not in JSP java code...

¿How can I solve it?

I was using tomcat previously and everything was OK but now I'm using glassfish the debugger doesn't stop on JSP's.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Delete Netbeans `cache` folder. If you're on Windows, goto `C:/Users/<your_name>/AppData/Local/Netbeans/` and delete `cache` folder. Restart Netbeans

Comment: Hi @Shashanth,  I tried and didn't work, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of things, I had to remove netbeans and installed it again and it solved the problem.
Maybe is a bug...